# Xcode C++ "Use of undeclared identifier" error with another class

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I've done some reading on the site here about undeclared identifier errors in xcode and C++. It usually seems like it comes from some small typo somewhere in the code, but I can't figure out for the life of me why I'm getting this error (also please note that I am a beginner in C++, so I may just be making some dumb mistake).

I'm writing my own library for artificial neural nets, and when I try to compile the 'Connection' class I get a bunch of "use of undeclared identifier 'Node'" error on every line in the Connection.h file that has the Node class somewhere in it. The classes Node and Connection are in the same namespace, and both cpp files are completely implemented for all functions declared in the header files. Here are the header files for both classes:

Connection.h (where I'm having the problems):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "Node.h"


namespace ANN{
    class Connection{



    public:

        Connection();
        Connection(boost::shared_ptr<Node> inNode, boost::shared_ptr<Node> outNode, float weight, int connID);
        ~Connection();

        virtual boost::shared_ptr<Node> getInputNode();
        virtual boost::shared_ptr<Node> getOutputNode();
        virtual void setInputNode(boost::shared_ptr<Node> inNode);
        virtual void setOutputNode(boost::shared_ptr<Node> outNode);
        virtual float getConnectionWeight();
        virtual void setConnectionWeight(float weight);

        virtual int getConnectionID();
        virtual void setConnectionID(int ID);

    protected:

        std::tuple<boost::shared_ptr<Node> , boost::shared_ptr<Node> , float> connection;
        int connectionID;

    private:


    };
}
```

In addition, I'm also getting some other errors in the line where I have the protected connection variable declared. I'm getting a "Parse issue : expected a type" and a "Parse issue : expected a member name or ';' after declaration specifiers".

Here is the Node.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "ActivationFunction.h"
#include "Connection.h"



namespace ANN{

    class Node{



    public:

        enum{
            INPUT = 0,
            HIDDEN = 1,
            OUTPUT = 2
        }kANNnodeTypes;

        Node(int num, int nodeType);
        ~Node();

        virtual void addOutputConnection(boost::shared_ptr<Connection> outputConnection);

        virtual void activateNode(ActivationFunction* activationObject);
        virtual void addInputSignalFromIncomingNode(float inputSignal, float connectionWeight);
        virtual int getNodeType();
        virtual int getNodeNum();
        virtual void loadInputAsSensorInput(float input);
        virtual bool isActivated();
        virtual bool isAllInputsReceived();
        virtual float getLatestOutput();
        virtual void resetNode();
        virtual void sendOutputToOutputNodes();
        virtual void setNumberOfInputConnections(int nC);
        virtual int getNumberOfInputConnections();

    protected:



        int nodeNum;
        int nodeType;
        int nInputConnections;
        int inputConnectionCount;
        float latestOutput;
        bool activated;
        float inputSignal;
        bool allInputsReceived;
        std::vector<float> outputWeights;
        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Node>> outputConnections;






    private:


    };
}
```

Comment: Node.h includes Connection.h. Connection.h includes Node.h. That can't happen. Neither of them need that include anyway, as a forward declaration would suffice.

Comment: ok good to know. in c++ why can't this happen? also what exactly does a forward declaration mean?

Comment: If Connection.h comes first, then the Node class it relies on hasn't been declared. Same thing vice-versa. And http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Chris! I have it working now. If you want to write an answer I can mark it as correct for you.

Comment: There has to be lots of other questions with circular include problems. One of those has to have a particularly good answer.